# Prevent variable from resetting after run ends

Tags: java, selenium, variables, junit, store

I'm running Integration Tests, where one of them does a checkout placing an order. There's a limit of orders for an account so, I want to have a counter that increments after placing orders and once it reaches the limit, change the email account.

I'm using Java and Selenium WebDriver, running the tests with JUnit.

I've tried using a static variable which increments +1 after an order is placed in the test. So, let's say that once it reaches 200, it resets to 0 and the email changes. The thing is that, once the test finishes, if I run it again, it starts from 0 again.

Comment: The variable's value is kept until the Virtual machine is closed. You have to keep this information outside of the context of the integration tests (external file, database...).

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should be good with @nikolas approach but the simplest approach would be updating the information to an environment variable and read it across the scripts. So that you don't have to worry about the r/w permissions when running in different machines.